# Formula Casteo Decimal asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas Tardes :

Estoy realizando una formula de Tasa Nominal para eso me dieron esta formula:

**=(((TEA+1)^(1/12))-1)*12**

```
decimal x = 3.141592654M ; 
double pi = (double) x ;
```

**dtorequest.Tasa** = `Convert.ToDecimal((Math.Pow((Convert.ToDecimal(pi) + 1), (1 / 12))) - 1) * 12;//40;`

Ya que mi **dtorequest.Tasa** es un variable decimal , me sale un error de decimal me podrian ayudar por favor

Un ejemplo :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El error que te sale de Overflow al hacer el casteo es por que el Decimal es mas grande de lo que el Double puede representar.

Por otro lado salvo que estés haciendo un gráfico con alguna curva, me suena raro que el número PI esté en una formula Financiera :)

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas definir tu propio pi sino en us lugar usa:

```
Math.PI
```

Además en la sgte expresión `(1/12)` deberás usar un `1.0` lo cual es un double de lo contrario será una división entera y el resultado no será el esperado

La línea completa sería

```
dtorequest.Tasa = Convert.ToDecimal((Math.Pow((Math.PI + 1),(1.0/12)) - 1) * 12)
```